# Textbox will not accept more than 1 character without disappearing in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, enter, keycode

```
private void btnClassNameA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbClassNameA.Visible = true;
        txtbClassNameA.Focus();
    }

private void txtbClassNameA_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) ;
        btnClassNameA.Text = txtbClassNameA.Text;
        txtbClassNameA.Visible = false;
    }
```

Upon clicking of a button, a text box appears.  I can't get it to accept more than 1 character at a time without disappearing.  It is supposed to disappear by pressing the enter key.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing the braces for your if?

Comment: You have `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) ;` which means when enter is presses execute nothing. `;` simply results in no-op. Rest of the code executes whenever any key is pressed and hence textbox disappears. You probably intended to wrap them in braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is equivalent to this:

```
private void txtbClassNameA_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { } // does nothing, just evaluates the condition
    btnClassNameA.Text = txtbClassNameA.Text;
    txtbClassNameA.Visible = false;
}
```

You have to change it like this:

```
private void txtbClassNameA_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
       btnClassNameA.Text = txtbClassNameA.Text;
       txtbClassNameA.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is not formatted correctly. Try it like this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
        btnClassNameA.Text = txtbClassNameA.Text;
        txtbClassNameA.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void txtbClassNameA_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            btnClassNameA.Text = txtbClassNameA.Text;
            txtbClassNameA.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

If that is your actual code, the semicolon might be throwing you off. Try this.

Comment: New it must have been something small ;) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a semicolon after your conditional.

Right now it is evaluating the conditional, and then moving on to update the text and make the box invisible.

```
private void txtbClassNameA_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
        {
            btnClassNameA.Text = txtbClassNameA.Text;
            txtbClassNameA.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Might give you better results.